# What is the difference between "systemctl restart" and "systemctl start"?

Tags: linux, restart, systemd

I have two services A and B where A is dependent on B which means A needs services provided by B, so in the A's service unit i have After and Requires set to B

```
After=B.service
Requires=B.service
```

Now when i stop the service B the service A also stops. And then after stopping B when i start it, the service A is not started and i have to start it manually.

```
systemctl stop B (A is also stopped)
systemctl start B (A is not started)
systemctl start A (I have to start A manually)
```

But if the service A is already stopped and i **restart** service B then the B and A both are started by the systemctl

```
systemctl stop A
systemctl restart B (B and A both are started)
```

My question is what is difference between `start` and `restart` for the kind of service unit i have for A?

Comment: I couldn't find any documentation about the behavior of `systemctl restart` when dependent services are present. Did you?

Answer (score 2):

systemctl start: Used to start a service (not reboot persistent)

systemctl stop:  Used to stop a service (not reboot persistent)

systemctl restart: Used to stop and then start a service

Comment: How is it different from `service apache2 reload` ?

Comment: This was already covered in the quesiton.

Answer (score 1):

You can always refer man pages for better understanding. Basically wants,requires,after are treated differently.

Dependencies react differently to wants and requires in a service file.

Start is simply starting a service when you want to use it but restart is mostly done when some changes are made in service files.
Refer this link for better understanding https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Systemd.